# Setting the text of a UILabel in an IBOutletCollection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, nsarray

I have three UILabels hooked up to an IBOutletCollection like so:

`@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *pids;`

In the Connections Inspector for File's Owner, there is an Outlet Collection "pids" with the three labels, so I believe everything is connected properly. What I am trying to do is set the text for a specific one of these labels, based off of a parameter `i` like so:

```
- (void)display:(NSInteger) i
{
    NSLog([[pids objectAtIndex:i] text]);
    [[pids objectAtIndex:i] setText: @"test"];
}
```

But this does not work. Each UILabel has some default text which I tried to display with the `NSLog` but that does not output anything. If `pids` is an NSArray of these labels, why doesn't the above code do anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the problem - the display method was being called before viewDidLoad, so the UILabels inside the pids array didn't exist on the screen yet.